# Aligning the button in a grid to center

Tags: css

I have the code below

```
<li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-grid-solo"><button id="btn1" type="submit"  >Submit</button></div>
                </fieldset>
            </li>
```

if i am using this the button is not center..
 how place it in center

Comment: that depends on your css for li and fieldset.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MELhg/).

Just add the following code in your css.

```
button{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont have idea about your css code. generally, to align some element in center you can use something like this

**CSS:**

```
 div.center{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    text-align:center; 
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-grid-solo center"><button id="btn1" type="submit"  >Submit</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found using text-align in css will work:

```
.ui-grid-solo { text-align:center; }
```